# Ofstream is not working in Dev C++. Any idea why not?

Tags: c++

I'm working on my first file handling in C++. I have written a simple program, but the problem is ofstream is now working in Dev C++. Any suggests?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;


int main(){

ofstream file_;
file_.open("mytext.txt");
file_ << "This is my first text file ";


file.close();
std::cin.get();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “not working”?

Comment: I am pretty sure that `ofstream` is working in Dev C++. Maybe your code is not producing the expected output, but then you should tell us what you expect and where these expectations dont fit with what you get

Comment: In case it's a compilation error you're seeing, you probably want to change `file.close()` to `file_.close()`. But unless you provide more details, all we can do is guess wildly…

Comment: Im gertting an error line 14 file.close(); is not declared in this scope.

Comment: file_.close() fixed my problem. Thanks Mindriot

Comment: do not use devc+++

Comment: Whats wrong using Dev c++ @dynamic

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mindriot said in his comment, this is  a compile error, use instead:

```
file_.close ();
```